# Insert two rows : on failure of one insert none

Tags: database, mysqli

I have 2 insert queries that insert single rows in two different tables.
I want a condition that if one query is not executed then even other should not.

I know transactions are the way to go , but my web host has disabled InnoDB engine because of which i cannot have transactions.

Is there a workaround for Myisam engine for this?

Any help highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: well, just delete first row if second failed

Comment: Can you provide sql for that?
i want to do this with pure sql

Comment: 1. you tagged your question with mysqli, which is a set of PHP functions. 2. I doubt you really need it. 3. I'm afraid, there is no way anyway. Try to reduce the number of limitations.

Comment: ya I am using it in php, but i want to reduce the second trip to DB server. So if i use php i will make 2 trips to server.I then planned  to use stored procedures.Cant we write a code like
result=INSERT INTO...
IF RESULT THEN
result2=INSERT INTO...
IF !result2 THEN
DELETE //First row

Answer (score 0):

> *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil*". Old Donald Knuth.

If you have some task to accomplish, do it whatever way you can. Just make it work. Do not invent imaginary obstacles out of nowhere to struggle with. You can make it with PHP code? Go for it. To tell you truth, a roundtrip to database is not *that* scary thing to be avoided at any cost.

So, write your algorithm in PHP and move on.